# Disabling Flash fallback option in mediaelement.js

Tags: javascript, html, mediaelement.js

I'm working with [`MediaElement.js`](http://mediaelementjs.com), and would like to disable the option where browsers without HTML5 `<video>` support get redirected to a Flash fallback. Unfortunately, despite looking over the docs, I haven't found a way to do so. If it can be done, how does one disable the Flash fallback option?

Answer (score 1):

```
new MediaElement('player1', {
  // remove or reorder to change plugin priority
  plugins: ['silverlight']
});
```